# Unity Button Prefab Coming in as Null

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, button

I have been having a problem all day now where my button prefab is coming in as null. The problem arose when I changed from using GameObject in my code to Button. I had to do this for my listener to apply properly. I am trying to create a list of save games from a file, and need to be able to differentiate between the buttons and chose to apply the listener to each one to return an integer. The specific error is  "The object you want to instantiate is null."
Here is my code

```
void Populate()
{
    Button newObj = Instantiate(NewSave, transform) as Button; // Create GameObject instance

    newObj.name = "NewSave";
    startList();
}
public void startList()
{
    Button newObj;
    int i = 0;

    clearList();
    foreach (PlayerType nextPlayer in GameManager.instance.saveStorage.returnSaves())
    {
        i++;
        // Create new instances of our prefab until we've created as many as is in list
        newObj = (Button)Instantiate(OldSaves, transform);

        //increment slot names
        Debug.Log(i);
        newObj.name = "Slot " + i.ToString();
        newObj.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(i));
        saveList.Add(i);
    }


}
```

If you notice structure problems with the specific button creation please do not harp, I have torn this section of code apart quite a few times with the various suggestions online.

Essentially I have 2 button prefabs, one for a new save button and another for the individual save slots. It passes the listener to the save/load function and determines which slot to save it to before sending it to or from the file. The problem is on the first creation of the button, which was working fine until I implemented my listener setup and had to switch to using buttons instead.

I made sure that the buttons are connected via the inspector, and believe it is specifically something to do with my prefab itself as when I moved the prefab initialization to another line it followed. Here are some screenshots of my setup.

[Inspector Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVc4F.png)

[Button Prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3RsC.png)

Thanks for any help that can help me narrow the problem down, most of the threads I have been through were simple fixes like they forgot to connect it in the inspector, or someone had multiple scripts on the same object. I hope that its just another stupid mistake a new set of eyes will see quickly. I will post additional info or screenshots as needed when I get on tomorrow after work.

Update:

I solved the problem. I tried the suggestions and was typing up what went wrong when I found out that one of my inspector references was not set. I assumed that by changing the original populate saves it would set the references accordingly, however there were 2 locations I had to change it because I already had the script set on the object. 
[populatesave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOhue.png)
I didn't catch it before because my save hierarchy has like 5 items each with multiple components, so when I attached it via the inspector I just went to the Master copy of my script. It was only jumping between my scripts and finding who calls what specifically that I happened to click on the one that actually hold my populateSave script. I am going to mark the second one as the answer because it was you asking me to find what was calling it that led me to figuring this out. Thanks a lot, it even explains why the saves were not looping right too, when I created it I set the number of saves to 23 for some reason lol.

I don't think I can mark the comment as the answer but still want to give you credit, can you post your comment as an answer or is that against the rules here?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/416119/argumentexception-the-prefab-you-want-to-instantia-3.html?childToView=416199). Also can you please edit your question to include the field types of `NewSave` and `OldSaves`?

Comment: Are these buttons currently in your scene? or are do you create them at the beginning of your scene?  Can you show us how you are calling the first method?  This isn't an issue but, since you are instantiating a button you don't need to use `as button` just a fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
Button newObj = Instantiate(NewSave, transform) as Button;
```

Instantiate (usually) returns a GameObject. This is a different type to Button. When you use "as" it tries to cast it into the correct type. If it can't, it returns null.

What you want is:

```
Button newObj = (Instantiate(NewSave, transform) as GameObject).GetComponent<Button>();
```

I would also recommend changing the variable name of that button.

Keep in mind, a Button is a component, which is different to a gameobject.